# ElasticSearch ingest pipeline with Grok pattern DATESTAMP_RFC2822

Tags: elasticsearch

When simulating an ElasticSearch ingest pipeline to process timestamps in the form `Thu, 19 Sep 2019 20:28:58 GMT`, Grok fails using the `DATESTAMP_RFC2822` [pattern](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns#L76).

Any suggestions as to what am I missing here?

Example:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline" :
  {
    "description": "testing...",
    "processors" : [
      {
        "grok" : {
          "field" : "message",
          "patterns" : [
            "%{DATESTAMP_RFC2822:initial_date}"
          ],
          "on_failure" : [
            {
              "set" : {
                "field" : "error",
                "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
              }
            },
            {
              "set" : {
                "field" : "grok_error",
                "value" : true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "1",
      "_source": {
        "message": "Thu 19 Sep 2019 20:28:58 GMT"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

...results in:

```
"Provided Grok expressions do not match field value: [Thu 19 Sep 2019 20:28:58 GMT]",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date filter cannot parse time zone names.
You can use %{DAY}, %{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{WORD}

WORD will match any word(not necessarily a time zone).
If you are using any particular time zone you can replace WORD with that time zone.